# NDK: keeping variables passed from java layer alive in c++ layer by copy by value

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Hi I have jobjectArray(array of Strings) passed from Java layer to JNI layer.
I want to keep it alive between jni calls, so I copied it by value. But data is getting corrupted once I switch between jni calls.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_package_class(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, ptr, jobjectArray ddls){
    int ddlCount = env->GetArrayLength(ddls);
    const char **ddls1 = (const char**)malloc(ddlCount);
    for (int i=0; i<ddlCount; i++) {
        jstring str = (jstring) env->GetObjectArrayElement(ddls, i);
        const char *rawStr = env->GetStringUTFChars(str, NULL);
        ddls1[i] = copyByValue(rawStr);
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(str,rawStr);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<ddlCount; i++){
           LOG("ddls1=%s", ddls1[i]);
    }
    //pass ddls1 to some class object
}
const char* copyByValue(const char* str) {
    int size = strlen(str);
    char* str1 = (char *) malloc((size+1)*sizeof(char));
    memcpy(str1, str, size);
    str1[size] = '\0';
    return str1;
}
```

Now when I loose this JNI context, data(ddls1) becomes corrupted. Sometime before changing JNI context, even while printing, it crashes.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here and what is best way to copy jni variables so that they don't become corrupted after we loose JNI context.

Comment: Try to figure out *what* is getting corrupted or lost: ddls1 (wherever you passed it, the posted copy is ephemeral), the array of pointers it points to, or the target memory of those pointers where the actual characters are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an extremely over-complicated solution for the actual problem, whatever that may be. And why do you use `memcpy` instead of `strcpy`? In fact, since this is C++ and not C, the safest and cleanest way is to use `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
std::vector<std::string> copies;

// ...

char const *rawStr = env->GetStringUTFChars(str, NULL);
std::string const copy(rawStr);
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(str, rawStr);
```

Now you can use the `copy` object safely; all low-level stuff has already been handled for you.

```
copies.push_back(copy);
```

> Please let me know what I am doing wrong here and what is best way to
>   copy jni variables so that they don't become corrupted after we loose
>   JNI context.

You are over-using pointers and ignore standard C++ classes.

I would store the `copies` object in a **static C++ variable**. Of course, then you may run into concurrency issues if the JNI function is used by different threads, so watch out for that if you use multi-threading.

An entirely different solution would be to just **store the original object in Java** and access it from C++ every time you need it, via a callback to Java using `GetMethodID` or `GetFieldID`.

Comment: Thanks, this solution was working fine already. I already had this solution, but just wanted to know what is wrong in using const char**. If possible, please tell any technical flaw in original solution.